# Finding the longest word in a file

Tags: c++, file, text, get, getline

Hi all I am trying to write a program that finds the longest line and word in a file us ifstream. I have got the program to find the longest line but am having trouble with it finding the longest word. This is what I have at the moment.

This is the error I am getting.

```
program1.cpp:44:30: error: ‘get’ was not declared in this scope                                                                   
          while (get(file,word))
```

From what I have learned, getline is used to get the actual line, while get is supposed to get the characters in that line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<getopt.h>
#include"stdio.h"
#include<fstream>
//#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   size_t longest = 0;
   string longestWord;
   int Lcount = 0;
   int Wcount = 0;
   int option;
   string line;
   string word;

    if(argc <= 1)
    {
       cout << "NO FILES\n";
       return 0;
    }
   else
   {

   for(int i = 1;i<argc;i++){
      ifstream file (argv[i]);
      if (!file.is_open() ){
      cout << argv[i] << " FILE NOT FOUND\n"; // watch out for /n
      }
     //else if(!file.close()){
        // cout << argv[i] << "NO FILES\n"; }
      else{
         while (getline(file,line))// Length of Longest Line
         {
            if(line.size() > longest){
               longest = line.size(); 
         }
            else if(line.size() == longest){// Number of lines with longest length
                     ++Lcount;}
         }
         while (get(file,word))
         {
            if(word.size() > longestWord.size()){
               longestWord = word; 
         }
            else if(word.size() == longestWord.size()){
                     ++Wcount;}
         }

   }
   }
   }

     while ((option = getopt (argc, argv, "c:")) != -1){
        switch (option)
        {
           case 'c': 
              {
              for(int i = 1;i<argc;i++){
                  ifstream file (argv[i]);

              cout << argv[i] << "\n";
              cout << longestWord << " (" << Wcount << ")" << "\n";
              cout << longest << " (" << Lcount << ")" << "\n";
                 break;
              }
              }

                 default: 
                 //cout << "UNRECOGNIZED FLAG\n";
              if(option != 'c'){
                 cout << "UNRECOGNIZED FLAG\n";
                 return 0;}

        }
     }

        //if (option != 'c')
           //cout << "UNRECOGNIZED FLAG\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your `get(file, word)` method.

Comment: [Which of those particular `get()` functions](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=get) did you mean to use?

Comment: I meant to use ifstream

Comment: What is a line - English sentence?  or   "to next '\n'"

Comment: What is a word (or perhaps, what substring characteristic might not be a  'word')?   Perhaps words do not have colon(s), underscore(s), comma(s), digit(s), must not start with digit.  Or might a word be any string between two white spaces?

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to your get function in the libraries you included. Try file>>word instead of get. Also ifstream again with a different variable to get the words to word. See http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/34420/ for reference.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, when I changed it to this:     while (file>>word(file,word)){                     i got this error

Comment: error: no match for call to ‘(std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}) (std::ifstream&, st
d::__cxx11::string&)’                                                                                                             
          while (file>>word(file,word))

Comment: Change it to just file>>word

Comment: I did that and it does compile, but the problem I am having is that I want the loop to get the characters in a word, similar to how getline gets the line(s) in a file.

Comment: Add ifstream file (argv[i]);
         if (!file.is_open() ){
          cout << argv[i] << " FILE NOT FOUND\n"; // watch out for /n
         } above the while(file>>word) again. The getline takes ifstream to the last. We just have to reset it.